# Error in nested RibbonApplicationMenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon

I want to build a `RibbonApplicationMenu`. Within it shall be a nested `RibbonApplicationMenuItem` or `RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem`, e.g. likes this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem x:Name="item1" Header="open project" ImageSource="../img/img1.png">
       <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="item11" Header="sub1" ImageSource="../img/img2.png" />
       <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="item12" Header="sub2" ImageSource="../img/img3.png" />
       <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="item13" Header="sub3" ImageSource="../img/img3.png" />
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem>
```

At first there is no error shown and the program can be built successfully.

When I continue work the entire section is labeled and an error is given:

> The index '0' is out of the valid range of the PathParameters-List
>   with the length '0'

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: This seems to be a designer-issue only. I agree it might be annoying, but not even google finds anything under this errormessage

Comment: Please, share a **verifiable** example.

Comment: Try using two forward slashes instead of one on the image source link `ImageSource="..//img/lifeUp2.jpg" `. It works for me... Let me know if that works for you, if it does I'll try and post an explanation on this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Binding="{Binding (0)}" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879168/what-does-binding-binding-0-mean)

Answer (score 8):

This is very easy to understand and to fix, but there is no real need to do that.

### The Reason

The issue is that in the standard ribbon templates there are many wrong placeholders

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding  (0)}" Value="True"/>
```

### The Fix

Long story short, you need to change the above into, for example:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding  Zero }" Value="True"/>
```

### How to do that?

That's not trivial, but you can do it with a little of attention..

You have to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Classic`

Then, let me start from the end... the objective is defining the following

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonButton}" >
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem}" >
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonApplicationMenuItem}" >
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonApplicationMenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

### The missing control templates

What is still missing? Three very big pieces of code containing the above `ControlTemplates`... but there is a trick to include them:

- move the cursor to (for example) `RibbonApplicationMenuItem` and locate the `Template` in the `Properties Window`
- click on the right `Ambient` and select `Convert to New Resource...`

  In conclusion you will run an overall replace from `(0)` to `Zero` through all of your xaml.

Again, this is intended as a pure academic exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time to check this solution before the bounty expires. So I will award the bounty now and probably accept it later.

Comment: The invalid binding syntax has been reported at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/545784/invalid-syntax-inside-ribbon-control-templates-bin.html

Comment: I answered a question that documents the process of getting the default `ControlTemplate` in the [How to Extract Default Control Template In Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio/28212036#28212036) question, here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Microsoft issue migrated to: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/647